# Media item (image) and RTE

Tags: media-library, richtext-editor

I'm running into an issue with using images in RTE. Images upload as expected into the medialibrary so no issues there. But when I insert the newly uploaded image in RTE it'll appear in Experience Editor view as a broken link. When requesting the image in a tab it gives a 404 (using the ashx-url as used in RTE).

Configs concerning media all seem to have the default value and after trying all I can think of I can only get it to work when publishing the image first. After publish the image works as expected in RTE. So it almost looks as if the RTE is looking for the image in the web-database, but that doesn't make sense to me as we are in the experience editor.

Does anybody have an idea what is going on here and how I can prevent having to do a publish of media first before it's usable in RTE?

Comment: Check in `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` if you have any custom value of `Media.MediaLinkServerUrl` setting. It may be configured that your images are loaded from CD server (or CDN) instead of from the CM server.

Comment: I checked the value and it's not set so it should get the images from the CM. I can't figure out why it doesn't